# Cannot construct instance of org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AccessToken

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jackson

My server app is both oauth2 client and authorziation server and I am trying to read a `ResponseEntity` with `org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AccessToken` as payload.

I've registered **OAuth2ClientJackson2Module** like so :

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.jackson2.OAuth2ClientJackson2Module;


@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.modules(new OAuth2ClientJackson2Module());
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build());
    }
}
```

Result is the following error :

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AccessToken` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1915)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:414)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1360)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1424)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:352)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:185)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:395)
```

Here is the official documentation : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/jackson.html

I have found those github issues which seems close to mine :

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9628#issuecomment-818715786
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8373

Any help will be appreciated !